# I can read data from a micro SD but the data I write to it gets lost. Is it completely broken?

Tags: sd-card

I am experiencing a very weird issue with a micro SD card. I can read data from it (as far as I can tell it's not corrupted) but I cannot write anything to it.

When I try to write data to it OSX seems to complete the operation, but if I eject the memory and reinsert it the new files I added/modified got lost.

I am using that micro SD with a Raspberry PI and what's very surprising is that if I try to put a new system imagine on it (I'm using `dd`) I don't get any error message, but as soon as I try to read it i get the old data.

Is my micro SD broken?

Comment: Is it [write-locked](http://techiedan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/SD-Card-lock.jpg)?

Comment: @Chipperyman no, it's in read/write mode. If I switch it to read only I get, as expected, a "Permission denied" error when I run `dd` and I can't create new files.

Comment: My problem is exactly the one reported here, which makes me think that my micro SD is broken since I cannot complete any of the suggested fixes.
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/is-my-raspberry-pi-permanently-damaging-sd-cards

Comment: Is it geniune? This sound a bit like overprovisioned flash area, which is common for fake SD cards.

Comment: It was the one I got with the RaspberryPi from their website. It doesn't have any manufacturer logo

Comment: Probably broken. Today's sd cards are very cheap, and that had to reflect somewhere.